# How to load a WPF FormattedText object (from RTF or RichTextBox)

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

My WPF app displays lots of text snippets at various places on a large canvas (a kind of post it note app)

I am currently rendering the text using FormattedText objects and 'drawing them' straight into Visual objects (for speed/efficiency)

Challenge I have is how to load/save/edit that rich text. I'd like to use a RichTextBox to edit the text - but I can't find a way to get the text out of the text box and into a FormattedText object (or visa versa)

Anyone know how this might be achieved? Only way I can think is to have some kind of 'serialise to/from RTF' capability on the FormattedText object - but that doesn't seem to exist.

Thanks

Comment: How about this: http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-transfer-rich-text-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link posted by Clemens above http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-transfer-rich-text-from.html addresses my issue.

Similar to fooook's answer - iterate through the inline objects and apply their attributes to a FormattedText object.

Shame that FormattedText doesn't support images (like NSAttributedString on iOS/OSX)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all of the inline objects inside of the RichTextBox.Document, Get all the dependency properties you are interested in, and then set them on a new FormattedText object.

```
var formattedTextToDraw = new List<FormattedText>();

foreach (var paragraph in RichTextBox.Document.OfType<Paragraph>())
{
    foreach(var inline in paragraph)
    {
        formattedTextToDraw.Add(new FormattedText(
            inline.Text, //Text
            inline.FontSize, //Fontsize
            inline.Foreground, //Color
            etc....) //Other properties for FormattedText constructor
    }
}
```